# Python - Extracting only necessary elements from a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract only the parts I need from the table.

```
    2555    texttext    0   100 100 0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2557    texttext    10  650 660 0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2564    texttext    0   30  30  0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2566    texttext    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2567    texttext    10  70  80  0   0   0   0   lowness 0
```

All I need is 'text text' and/ immediately followed by two numbers and 'low' as shown below.

```
    texttext    0   100 lowness
    texttext    10  650 lowness
    texttext    0   30  lowness
    texttext    0   0   lowness
    texttext    10  70  lowness
```

I tried this but failed.

```
text = """
    2555    texttext    0   100 100 0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2557    texttext    10  650 660 0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2564    texttext    0   30  30  0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2566    texttext    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2567    texttext    10  70  80  0   0   0   0   lowness 0
"""

for a in text.split('\n'):
    if a == "":
        continue
    else:
        print(a)
        m = re.match('(^\D\d*\D)(\w*\s)(\d*\s)(\d*\s)(\d*\s\d*\s\d*\s\d*\s\d*\s)(\w+)', a)
        print(m)
        print(m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(6))
```

I tried to group by regex and get the parts, but I got the following error: Help / print(m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(6))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Why not split each line by whitespaces and grab desired array elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely want to use a regular expression:

```py
import re

text = """
    2555    texttext    0   100 100 0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2557    texttext    10  650 660 0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2564    texttext    0   30  30  0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2566    texttext    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   lowness 0
    2567    texttext    10  70  80  0   0   0   0   lowness 0
"""
pattern = re.compile(
    r"\s*\d+\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\w+)\s+"
)

for line in text.strip().split('\n'):
    match = re.search(pattern, line)
    print(*match.groups())
```

Output:

```
texttext 0 100 lowness
texttext 10 650 lowness
texttext 0 30 lowness
texttext 0 0 lowness
texttext 10 70 lowness
```

But if it is really the case that it's always the same number of space-separated substrings of characters, then you might really be better off just splitting the lines by spaces:

```py
for line in text.strip().split('\n'):
    parts = line.split()
    print(parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[9])
```

Same output.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for a in text.split('\n'):
    if a == "":
        continue
    else:
        parts = a.split()
        print(parts[1],parts[2],parts[3],parts[9])
```

Comment: Just fyi, [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) by default uses (any) whitespace as separator. So the space in `split(' ')` is redundant. It also then discards empty strings from the result. So you won't need to use `strip()` on the parts again. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting a match, because you are only matching a single `\D` and a single `\s` which match a single character.

But in the example data, there are more repetitions of the same characters to get to the next match.

If you fix that, you will get a match but with the wrong data in the groups, see https://regex101.com/r/v3ddai/1

---

Instead, you can just use 2 capture groups.

As there always seem to be digits present, you can change `\d*` to `\d+`

```
^\s*\d+\s+(\w+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+)\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XOeJbu/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
for e in text.splitlines():
    if e:
        ls = e.split()
        print(ls[1:4] + ls[-2:-1])

['texttext', '0', '100', 'lowness']
['texttext', '10', '650', 'lowness']
['texttext', '0', '30', 'lowness']
['texttext', '0', '0', 'lowness']
['texttext', '10', '70', 'lowness']
```

Comment: [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines), nice, +1 for expressiveness.